# Hibernate Criteria not executing

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I am having trouble getting the hibernate criteria to execute, here is my code

```
Session session = HibernateFactory.openSession();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Title.class);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like( "TITLE.title", "W%" ));
            List titles = criteria.list();
```

When I check the size of titles, it prints 0, but, when I do

```
org.hibernate.Query query2 = session.createSQLQuery( "SELECT * FROM TITLE WHERE TITLE.title LIKE 'W%'");
            List<Title> list2 = query2.list();
```

and check the size of list2 I get 1, what am I doing wrong?

Edit 1: Also my sql_show is set to true, in the 1st case it does not print the query, while in the second case it does, I need to solve this too.

Comment: Could it be a case issue? SQL compares W% and w% where hibernate is taking it only as W% ?

Comment: I've checked that too. My criterion content is TITLE.title like 'W%', but still no luck :(

Comment: Have you tried turning on trace logging and seeing the actual HQL executed?

Comment: Like I have mentioned my trace logging is on, but the actual HQL does not get printed when using createCriteria for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like( "TITLE.title", "W", MatchMode.Start ));
```

Should do what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

`Restrictions.like()` accepts the property name of the mapped entity only

How about this?

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like( "title", "W%" ));
```

Comment: I had my criteria setup like that 1st, when it didn't help, I changed to have the table name as well. But does no change.